# Failure trying to manage apt sources with Puppet

Tags: debian, puppet, apt

I'm trying to get Puppet to manage my Debian apt sources.list, however, catalog compilation fails with this error:

> Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: ::apt::config_files is not a hash or array when accessing it with list at /etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/apt/manifests/setting.pp:45 on node [hostname]

I have no idea where I should provide ::apt::config_files or what I'd need to put in it. My manifests contain the following:

```
# site.pp
node <hostname> {
  include roles::myrole
}

# myrole.pp
class roles::myrole.pp {
  include profiles::apt
}

# apt.pp
class profiles::apt {

  # Get our apt sources out of Hiera.
  $hiera_apt_sources = hiera_hash(apt_sources)

  # Create our apt sources.
  create_resources(apt::source, $hiera_apt_sources)

}

# hieradata (yaml)
apt_sources:
  'debian_stable':
    location: 'ftp.be.debian.org/debian/'
    release: 'stable'
    repos: 'main contrib non-free'
  'debian_security':
    location: 'security.debian.org'
    release: 'updates'
    repos: 'main contrib non-free'
```

Am I missing something obvious here? I've looked through the documentation at [the forge](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/apt) and [this Puppetlabs post](https://puppetlabs.com/blog/module-of-the-week-puppetlabs-apt-pull-apt-strings-with-puppet) and some other hits on Google.

I also tried to `include apt` in apt.pp, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out namespacing was the problem.

In order for this to work I need the MODULE 'apt' to be called. By specifying `include apt` or `class { 'apt': }` in the class `profiles::apt`, it tries to include or call itself. Changing to `class { '::apt': }` (absolute name) fixes the problem.